# Convert array to json without cycle

Tags: php, json, yii2

I have an array of 500k values, and I need to convert it into one big json object, I could not find such a possibility in the helper. Another important point I do not want to twist the foreach, because it is not productive.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Json class in yii2 from

```
yii\helpers\Json;
```

It contain methods such as :

```
Json::encode();
Json::decode();
```

These methods directly converts yii2 activerecord objects into json array.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know for them. I for some reason thought that he takes one object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering if the below line won't be sufficient ?

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Comment: I need to do this on php

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES5 Array.reduce for this use case,if you are working on es5.

```js
var array500Values=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var json500 = array500Values.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  acc[val]=val;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(json500);
```

Comment: I need to do this on php